# Create a single element instead of multiple tag

Tags: html, css

Code works as I expected, but is there any possibility to make it in a single tag or in two tags. In  id="vCurVal" I get values using scriptlet tag which comes from an other jsp's url.

```css
.labelbold {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #993333;
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: verdana
}
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var CurrentVal = '<%=strCurrentValue%>';
document.getElementById("vCurVal").innerHTML = CurrentVal;
</script>
```

```html
        <div>
            <label class="labelbold" style="font-weight: bold; float:left;">ORDER NO - &nbsp; </label>
            <div id="vCurVal" class="labelbold" style="font-weight: bold; float:left;"></div>
            <label class="labelbold" style="font-weight: bold; float:left;">&nbsp ALREADY EXIST &nbsp; </label>
        </div>
```

Output:

`ORDER NO -  37 ALREADY EXIST`

And also I tried this way,

```html
<legend class="labelbold" style="font-weight: bold;" >&nbsp;&nbsp; ORDER NO - &nbsp; <label id= "vCurVal" style="color:red;"> </label>&nbsp; ALREADY EXIST &nbsp;</legend>
```

Output

`ORDER NO -   ALREADY EXIST`

This is not showing the dynamic value 37 as I expected.

Values may get changed according to the input.

Comment: Why you need the extra label tag if you want the ALREADY EXIST aside the ORDER NO- you can do it with single div and label tag

Comment: Can you be more specific with your exact requirement

Comment: For a `label` tag to be correct, you need an  associated form element. Use `span` instead.

Comment: There seems to be some information missing from the question. As currently written, the answer is yes, you can put all the text "ORDER NO -  37 ALREADY EXIST" in one element without loss of functionality. Do you need something more?

Comment: @MrLister I edited the question and gave the required information as you said. Thanks you for assisting. If it is yes, could you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: @SilverShineSarath OK, answer below. But your edit does raise more questions. 1) If the code really looks like `var CurrentVal = '<%=strCurrentValue%>';`, why not put `<%=strCurrentValue%>';` directly in the text in the HTML part? And 2) Wait, is all this really happening in the legend of a fieldset?

Comment: @MrLister I did, but I didn't get the value. And the variable is required to do some validations in JavaScript. I just mentioned only a part of the process. And I passed that variable and I got the value. Yes it's happening in legend. But again I changed to label tag. And I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is this. There is no need for an outer container div, and yes, you can put the output element inside the labelbold element, so that there is only two nested elements in total rather than 4 as in your example.
Note that I used an `<output>` element here, but you can use a `<span>` or any inline element if you want.

```js
var CurrentVal = '0.17 amp';
document.getElementById("vCurVal").innerHTML = CurrentVal;
```

```css
.labelbold {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  color: #993333;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="labelbold" style="float:left">ORDER NO - &nbsp;<output id="vCurVal"></output>&nbsp; ALREADY EXIST &nbsp;</div>
```

<sub>(A solution without an inner output element is possible (use e.g. `%1` in the text at the position the output needs to be, and have the JavaScript be `innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(/%1/, currentVal)`, but I can't really recommend such a level of "cleverness" just for the sake of omitting one element from the source.)</sub>